# CheckBox does not fire CheckedChanged event when unchecking the checkbox Dynamically in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, checkbox, updatepanel

Here I am having a checkbox in this update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="LVCheckBoxes">
    <ContentTemplate>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="New" Text="New" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="checkBoxCheck" /></li>
            </ul>
    </ContentTemplate>
</<asp:UpdatePanel >
```

All I am Trying to do is uncheck it on click of linkbutton.
Which is working fine.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LbUnCheck" runat="server" OnClick="LbUnCheck" ToolTip="New">UnCheck</asp:LinkButton>
```

But Along with it I also want to fire the check changed Event Which is not firing

```
protected void LbUnCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)LVCheckBoxes.FindControl(lb.ToolTip);
        cb.CheckedChanged += checkBoxCheck;
        cb.Checked = false;

}


protected void checkBoxCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do something

}
```

I even Tried this using JQuery but it is not working quite as expected.

Help Appreciated..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling the CheckBox check event method (`checkBoxCheck`) from the Link Button click event method (`LbUnCheck`). Something like this:

```
protected void LbUnCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)LVCheckBoxes.FindControl(lb.ToolTip);

        // cb.CheckedChanged += checkBoxCheck; // REMOVE THIS LINE

        cb.Checked = false;
        checkBoxCheck(null, null); // NOTICE THIS IS AFTER SETTING cb.Checked = false;
}


protected void checkBoxCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanx man it worked but I had to make it like this -> checkBoxCheck(cb, null); in case of multiple checkox

Comment: @raw_hitt That is fair. You can pass your desired checkbox and access it by the `sender` parameter in the `checkBoxCheck` method and go from there. Happy coding